# Having trouble storing input in array

Tags: java, arrays

I'm currently learning how to work with **arrays** and I am having some troubles with one of my arrays storing input.

I attempted to create two nested **for loops** that cycle back and forth after each input but one of the loops is scanning, but not storing, the input i need it to my second array.

My understanding of the logic of nested for loops is not the best so I think it has something to do with that.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

My source code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays; 

public class PlayerRoster {

  public static void inputStats(Scanner scan) {
    int [] number = new int [5];
    int [] rating = new int [5]; 
    int jerseyNumber = 1; 

    for(int i = 0; i < number.length; i++){
    System.out.printf("Enter player %d's jersey number\n", jerseyNumber);  
      number[i] = scan.nextInt();


      for(int j = 0; j < 1; j++){
      System.out.printf("Enter players %d's rating\n", jerseyNumber);
      rating[j] = scan.nextInt(); 
      jerseyNumber++; 
    }
  }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(number)); 
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(rating));
  }




  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in); 
    inputStats(scan); 





    return;
  }
}
```

Comment: No need for the nested loop.

Comment: Your nested loop will only execute once, for `j = 0` and thus `rating[j] = scan.nextInt();` will _always_ write the input to `rating[0]`. I assume you want to get rid of the inner loop and use `rating[i] = scan.nextInt();`

Comment: A tip for future exercises: create an object that takes the number and rating and build on array of those objects. That makes it easier to handle corresponding data, especially if you want to sort the arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Since your arrays are the same length you don't need the second loop.

1 Loop for both arrays is enough.
like so:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays; 

public class PlayerRoster {

  public static void inputStats(Scanner scan) {
    int [] number = new int [5];
    int [] rating = new int [5];  

    for(int i = 0; i < number.length; i++){
    System.out.printf("Enter player %d's jersey number\n", i+1);  
      number[i] = scan.nextInt();



      System.out.printf("Enter players %d's rating\n", i+1);
      rating[i] = scan.nextInt(); 


  }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(number)); 
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(rating));
  }
```

You also do not need the jerseyNumber var as it does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you expect output like this

```
[1,3,5,2,6]  // number
[3,4,3,5,4]  // rating
```

Just replace your `inputStats` with this

```
public static void inputStats(Scanner scan) {
    int [] number = new int [5];
    int [] rating = new int [5]; 

    for(int i = 0; i < number.length; i++){
      System.out.printf("Enter player %d's jersey number\n", i+1);  
      number[i] = scan.nextInt();
      rating[i] = scan.nextInt(); // changed Line. 
  }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(number)); 
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(rating));
}
```

**Changes:**

1.Replaced this

```
System.out.printf("Enter player %d's jersey number\n", jerseyNumber);
```

with

```
System.out.printf("Enter player %d's jersey number\n", i+1);
```

**Reason:** This is not necessary but why to use an extra variable.

2.replace this code

```
for(int j = 0; j < 1; j++){
      System.out.printf("Enter players %d's rating\n", jerseyNumber);
      rating[j] = scan.nextInt(); 
      jerseyNumber++; 
    }
```

with

```
  rating[i] = scan.nextInt();
```

**Reason:** for loop is just replacing index 0 of rating each time it executes

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I don't think you have anything wrong with the loops except for the fact that inner loop(2nd `for` statement) is unnecessary as you are reading only one rating for each player.

So you could directly write

```
System.out.printf("Enter players %d's rating\n", jerseyNumber);
rating[i] = scan.nextInt();
```

without putting it in a for loop.

Recognize how I used `i` instead of `j` as index variable because `i` maintains the player's count `j` is just a variable to loop rating input once. As the second loop is inside first loop it happens once( counted by `j`) every time outer loop is executed (counted by `i`).

Now, because you have used `j` as index for ratings array, Every player's rating input is overriding the first player's rating i.e. first element in ratings array but not storing it in next index which is counted by `i`.

Hence, Your complete code would be:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays; 

public class PlayerRoster {

  public static void inputStats(Scanner scan) {
    int [] number = new int [5];
    int [] rating = new int [5]; 
    int jerseyNumber = 1; 

    for(int i = 0; i < number.length; i++){
      System.out.printf("Enter player %d's jersey number\n", jerseyNumber);  
      number[i] = scan.nextInt();

      System.out.printf("Enter players %d's rating\n", jerseyNumber);
      rating[j] = scan.nextInt(); 

      jerseyNumber++; 
    }

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(number)); 
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(rating));
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in); 
    inputStats(scan); 
    return;
  }
}
```